# C# using published programm on another system

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, publishing

i made a Windows-forms application with VS2017 in C# (.NET 4.6.1) with the Nuget package "emgu.CV". On my Dev-Machine (Win 10 Home Premium) i can use everything and the program works fine (I published the program and get a folder with setup.exe and some other folders).  But as soon as i install the program on the system where the program should run (Win 7, .NET 4.6.1 installed), i can install it but it won't start. I see the program in the task-manager for about 5 secs and then it dissapears.

Any ideas what's the problem here? I guess the Nuget-package is included in the exe or am i wrong?

Comment: Same issues happend with me for windows 7 and 10.. but I would Like to suggest  you to debug it...Edit your app to use some try catch cases for initial phases... and try to print error on windows message box if any. you will get to know at which stage you are getting error. This might help.. This is just general advice for every possible case. And make sure your setup project has everything required to run the application. I hope you have used that setup project on your Dev pc also just to make sure your setup project is complete with every dll file required.

Comment: Usha phulwani: thanks for the input, i will install the vs2017 on the win7 machine and try to make the program run there, thanks for the input :) i will give a feedback as soon as i find a solution

Comment: I think you should first try to install your application in your Dev machine using your setup project  If you have not done that yet.. and I dont think that at this time you need to setup VS on another machine.. Make  Some changes in application and Showing  error messages in  Message Box might help you...

Comment: I found a solution for my problem. Instead of Publishing my program i just released it (VS2017 Setting) and copied the Release-Folder on the Win7 machine. Works fine